# Managing state in angular2 application - side effects?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

This is more of a general question, but based on Victor Savkin  post  [Managing state in angular2](http://victorsavkin.com/post/137821436516/managing-state-in-angular-2-applications)

Let's consider approach described there that uses RxJs:

```
interface Todo { id: number; text: string; completed: boolean; }
interface AppState { todos: Todo[]; visibilityFilter: string; }

function todos(initState: Todo[], actions: Observable<Action>): Observable<Todo[]> {
  return actions.scan((state, action) => {
    if (action instanceof AddTodoAction) {
      const newTodo = {id: action.todoId, text: action.text, completed: false};
      return [...state, newTodo];
    } else {
      return state;
    }
  }, initState);
}
```

All is fine, but let's add few more requirements:

- Upon adding new Todo item, its text should be sent to the backend and analysed to extract possible due date and location.
- If Todo item has due date, it should be added to my Google calendar

So if i add Todo "Get my hair done at Sally's Saloon on Thursday", with first call i would get from backend Sally's Saloon and date which is set to this weeks (or next weeks) Thursday and second call would add this todo to my Google calendar and mark item as in calendar.

So my new Todo item structure might look something like this:

```
interface Todo { 
  id: number; 
  text: string; 
  completed: boolean; 
  location?: Coordinates; 
  date?: Date; 
  inCalendar?: boolean; 
  parsed?: boolean;
}
```

And now i have two side effects :

1. After todo has been added i need to parse the text
2. After date has been added to Todo, i need to add it to calendar.

How do i deal with these side effects in this approach? Redux says that reducers should be kept clean, and they also have a notion of Sagas.

**Option 1 - fire new event(s) for side effects when todo is added**

```
function todos(initState: Todo[], actions: Observable<Action>): Observable<Todo[]> {
  return actions.scan((state, action) => {
    if (action instanceof AddTodoAction) {
      const newTodo = {id: action.todoId, text: action.text, completed: false};
      actions.onNext(new ParseTodoAction(action.todoId));
      return [...state, newTodo];
    } else if (action instanceOf ParseTodoAction){
      const todo = state.find(t => t.todoId === action.todoId)
      parserService
      .parse(todo.todoId, todo.text)
      .subscribe(r => actions.onNext(new TodoParsedAction(todo.todoId, r.coordinates, r.date)))
    } else {
      return state;
    }
  }, initState);
}
```

But this will fail, because new todo is not yet available on the state. 
I could of course use only `TodoParsedAction` and instead of `ParseTodoAction` just invoke backend call inline, but this would also assume that backend call will take longer to process, and by the time it finishes state will already have that new Todo item which is trouble waiting to happen.

**Option 2 - subscribe to actions and check each todo for missing properties**

```
actions
.flatMap(todos => Observable.from(todos))
.subscribe(todo => {
  if (!todo.coordinates && !todo.parsed) {
     parserService
      .parse(todo.todoId, todo.text)
      .subscribe(r => actions.onNext(new TodoParsedAction(todo.todoId, r.coordinates, r.date)))
  }
  if (todo.date && todo.inCalendar === undefined) {
    calendarService
      .add(todo.text, todo.date)
      .subscribe(_ => actions.onNext(new TodoInCalendarAction(todo.todoId, true)))
  }
})
```

But this somehow does not feel right - shouldn't be everything managed by actions, and should i always loop through all of todo items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your option 1 can't work as stated: `actions` is an `Observable<Action>` observables are read-only and `onNext` isn't part of that API.  You need an `Observer<Action>` to support option 1.  This highlights the real flaw of option 1: your state function (same thing as a Redux reducer) needs to be *pure* and side-effect free.  That means they cannot and should not dispatch more actions.

Now in the blog article you reference, indeed the code is really passing in a Subject, which is both Observer and Observable.  So you probably *do* have an onNext.  But I can tell you that recursively publishing data to a Subject while you are handling data being published by that Subject will get you into no end of trouble and is rarely worth the headaches to make work correctly.

In Redux, the typical solution to invoking backend processing to enrich your state would be to dispatch multiple actions at the beginning when you have already decided to dispatch `AddTodo`.  This can often be done by using redux-thunk and dispatching functions as "smart actions":

Instead of:

```
export function addToDo(args) {
    return new AddToDoAction(args);
}
```

you'd do:

```
export function addToDo(args) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(new AddToDoAction(args)); // if you want to dispatch the Todo before parsing
        dispatch(parseToDo(args)); // handle parsing
    };
}

export function parseToDo(args) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        if (thisToDoNeedsParsing(args)) {
            callServerAndParse(args).then(result => {
                  // dispatch an action to update the Todo
                  dispatch(new EnrichToDoWithParsedData(result));
            });
        }
    };
}

// UI code would do:
dispatch(addToDo(args));
```

The UI dispatches a smart action (thunk) which will dispatch the `AddToDoAction` to get the unparsed todo in your state (your UI can choose to not show it until the parse completes if you want).  It then dispatches another smart action (thunk) which will actually call the server to get more data then dispatch an `EnrichToDoWithParsedData` action with the results so that your Todo can be updated.

As for updating of the calendar...you can probably use the pattern above (inserting calls to `possiblyUpdateCalendar()` in both `addToDo` and `parseToDo` so that if the todo has all the stuff you need, it can update the calendar and when that finishes dispatch an action to mark the todo as added.

Now this example I've shown is Redux-specific and I don't think the RxJs-based example you are working from has anything like a thunk.  One way to add support for this in your scheme is to add a `flatMap` operator to the subject that goes something like this:

```
let actionStream = actionsSubject.flatMap(action => {
    if (typeof action !== "function") {
        // not a thunk.  just return it as a simple observable
        return Rx.Observable.of(action);
    }
    // call the function and give it a dispatch method to collect any actions it dispatches
    var actions = [];
    var dispatch = a => actions.push(a);
    action(dispatch);

    // now return the actions that the action thunk dispatched
    return Rx.Observable.of(actions);
});

// pass actionStream to your stateFns instead of passing the raw subject
var state$ = stateFn(initState, actionStream);

// Now your UI code *can* pass in "smart" actions:
actionSubject.onNext(addTodo(args));
// or "dumb" actions:
actionSubject.onNext(new SomeSimpleAction(args));
```

Notice all of that code above is in the code that *dispatches* an action.  I didn't show any of your state function.  Your state function would be pure and something like:

```
function todos(initState: Todo[], actions: Observable<Action>): Observable<Todo[]> {
  return actions.scan((state, action) => {
    if (action instanceof AddTodoAction) {
      const newTodo = {id: action.todoId, text: action.text, completed: false};
      return [...state, newTodo];
    } else if (action instanceof EnrichTodoWithParsedData) {
      // (replace the todo inside the state array with a new updated one)
    } else if (action instanceof AddedToCalendar) {
      // (replace the todo inside the state array with a new updated one)
    }
    } else {
      return state;
    }
  }, initState);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. Everything looks really good. One thing that i don't quite like is that i must insert calls to `possiblyUpdateCalendar` in both addToDo and parseToDo (ok, for this simple example it works, but let's say i have a lot of actions that can add date on Todo, so in each of those i will have to add that `possiblyUpdateCalendar`). 
Another question - what if Todos are interdependent? If i add a date on Todo i must revalidate dates on adjacent todos in the backend?

Comment: To your question about interdependencies: Not shown in my example is the fact that redux-thunks get a second argument (`getState`) which allows these so-called "smart actions" to actually access the entire state tree.  So you can examine the state and apply any logic you need to determine exactly what further actions to dispatch or what server calls to make.  So it would be easy to walk through the todos and gather up all the ones that need an update and send them to the server for processing, then dispatch an action when the server returns to update state.

Comment: As for the multiple calls to `possiblyUpdateCalendar`: I don't have a good solution to that at the moment.  I've not had that problem come up enough in my projects to find or devise a clean solution.